# .Net MVC - How to render images in the file system

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, forms, model-view-controller

I am trying to simply display some images in a slidereel having been uploaded via a basic html form. Currently, the action method from the form stores the path of the images in the database as part of a slide object/element and then saves them to the stored location.

Then in my index view I have partial view that gets given a list of slide objects and uses the image path stored in the database as the image elements src. The correct ppaths are being retrieved but the images are failing to load. I have even copy pasted the src path from firebug and put it in the browser and file explorer to check that the image does in-fact exist at that path. I don't know why it is failing to load the images even though they exist where the src states it should be.
I have tried hard coding a relative path to a file in my content directory, and this works, but obviously that doesnt help me when it comes to using the uploaded images. Is it something to do with the full file path (i.e. c:/...) or is it the fact they are in app data?

Here is my forms action method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("create")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Slide model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return View(model);
   }

   var user = await GetLoggedInUser();

   if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.Id))
   {
      model.Id = model.Title;
   }

   model.Id = model.Id.MakeUrlFriendly();
   model.Created = DateTime.Now;
   model.AuthorId = user.Id;

   if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
   {
      try
      {
         var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
         var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);    
         var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/slides"), fileName + extension);

         for (int i = 1; System.IO.File.Exists(path); i++)
         {
            path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/slides"), fileName + "_" + i.ToString() + extension);
         }

         file.SaveAs(path);
         model.Image = path;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         ModelState.AddModelError("key", e);
         return View(model);
      }
   }

   try
   {
      _repository.Create(model);
      return RedirectToAction("index");
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      ModelState.AddModelError("key", e);
      return View(model);
   }
}
```

and here is my action method to populate the partial view:

```
public async Task<PartialViewResult> Slideshow()
{
   var slides = _slides.GetPublishedSlides();

   if (!slides.Any())
   {
      //return (PartialView("_Banner"););
   }

   return PartialView("_Slideshow", slides);
}
```

and here is the partial view itself:

```
@model IEnumerable<demo.Models.Slide>

<!-- BEGIN .slideshow -->
<div class="slideshow radius-full">
    <!-- BEGIN .flexslider -->
    <div class="flexslider radius-full loading" control-nav="true" data-speed="10000" data-transition="slide">
        <!-- BEGIN .slides -->
        <ul class="slides">
            @foreach (var slide in Model)
            {
                <li>
                    <!-- BEGIN .sixteen columns -->
                    <div class="sixteen columns">
                        <a class="feature-img radius-full" href="@slide.Link" rel="bookmark" title="@slide.Title">
                            <img src="@slide.Image" alt="@slide.Title" /> // ~/Content/img/demoslide.png works
                        </a>   
                    <!-- END .sixteen columns -->
                    </div>
                </li>
            }
        <!-- END .slides -->
        </ul>
    <!-- END .flexslider -->
    </div>
<!-- END .slideshow -->
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is because of you specify a physical path (Server.MapPath) on the server in this line.

```
path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/slides"), fileName + "_" + i.ToString() + extension);
```

You should use a virtual path instead.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what should be used in place of server.mappath?

Comment: A physical path is required because it's saving it to the application's data (this is in the POST method).  That part is correct.  It's the view code that does not point to the correct location (or rather, in the correct format).

Comment: I mean, usually you should not save absolute full path in database. It would be better if you can save a relative path (or just a file name) and map it to virtual path using the following line:
<img src="@Url.Content(slide.Image)" />

Answer (score 0):

When you "copy pasted the src path .. and put it in the browser and file explorer .. the image does exist at that path" your source path begins with "C:\".  (or some other drive letter)

When you specify `img src=`, you can't use "C:\".  You need to use "http://site/..." etc.

Change

```
model.Image = path;
```

to

```
model.Image = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
```

then change your `<a>` to:

```
<img src="@(Url.Content("~/App_Data/uploads/slides/") + @slide.Image)" ...
```

(or store just the filename part or the "~/.." part earlier in the code).

The key is `@Url.Content` to convert your site's path to an 'href' url.

Always check your rendered html (browser view-source) to see what it in the `a src=` and imagine how it would loaded from another PC (C:..image) won't exist on another PC.

Browsers generally block anything in html pointing at "C:\" these days for security reasons.